# Adding variables in python 3.4

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and am using python 3.4. I am trying to build a simple calculator. However, I keep running into this odd bug that 'incorrectly adds numbers'.
say I want to do 1+1, instead of getting 2 I am getting 11.

I have tried several ways to code the problem but I still end up getting a wrong answer.

```
numOne = input("what is ur first number:- ")

numTwo = input("what is ur second number:- ")

add = numOne + numTwo

print(add)
```

Say numOne = 1, and numTwo = 1. Instead of getting 2, I am getting 11.

Comment: You're concatenating strings rather than adding integers. Check the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your `input()` which gives a string, to a int via `int(input())` as follows.

```
numOne = int(input("what is ur first number:- "))

numTwo = int(input("what is ur second number:- "))

add = numOne + numTwo

print(add)
```

The output will look like:

```
what is ur first number:- 2
what is ur second number:- 3
5
```